# Two function have the same render_to_response template

Tags: django

Why my form is not displayed in example.html?

The two functions can not have the same `render_to_response` template name (example.html)?

models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

views

```
def show(request):
    a = A.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = XForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.cleaned_data['f']


            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = XForm()
    return render_to_response('example.html', {'a': a, 'form': form})


def show_f(request, a_id):
    #how to access to data from form?
    f = form.cleaned_data['f']
    A.objects.filter(id = a_id).update(quantity = f)

    return render_to_response('example.html')
```

example.html:

```
{% for x in a %}
{{ x.name }}

        <form action="/show_f/{{x.id}}/" method="post"/>
        {{form}}
        <input type="submit" value="Run"/>
        </form>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT:

I would like for each object from the database to display a form field, and after entering the quantity and submitting the form run show_f method (UPDATE quantity)

Comment: What view were you calling that won't show the form on the template? There's no reason to expect the form if the query set is empty, for example. What errors, if any, do you get? Please add anything that could be helpful to us for answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

How are you expecting this to work? If `show` renders the template, `a` will be present but `form` will not, so you'll get a set of empty forms. If `show_f` renders the template, `form` will be present but `a` will not, so the for loop will have nothing to iterate through and the result will be empty.

Exactly what are you trying to do? There's no problem with having two views rendering the same template, but they both have to actually provide the information the template needs to render.

Comment: I edited the question. I would like for each object from the database to display a form field, and after entering the quantity and submitting the form run show_f method (UPDATE quantity)

Comment: But you're not defining a form in the `show` function, so how is it supposed to display one?

Answer (score 0):

As explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template

A form should be rendered using, for example: {{ form.as_ul }}